# Разделение слов и словосочетаний в параграфе

Tags: javascript

Задача у меня следующая: разбить слова и словосочетания в предложении. У меня возникла сложность со словосочетаниями. Чтобы как то отделить слова от словосочетаний, я вынес словосочетания в отдельный span.

Привожу пример, что имею на данный момент.

```js
let text = "<p>Привет, как <span>твои дела</span>? Это тестовое сообщение.</p>";
let myArray = text.split("<p>").join("").split("</p>");
myArray.pop(myArray.length - 1); // Тут получаю массив из параграфов (если их будет несколько)
myArray.map((item, index) => {
  let arr = item.split(/\s+/); // Тут массив слов, который получил разбиением через пробелы (именно тут надо как то учитывать словосочетания из span)
  console.log(arr)
})
```

В итоге надо получить на выходе следующее

```
['Привет,', 'как', 'твои дела?', 'Это', 'тестовое', 'сообщение.']
```

А у меня вот так

```
["Привет,", "как", "<span>твои", "дела</span>?", "Это", "тестовое", "сообщение."]
```

Comment: Сначала надо выделять словосочетания, и только потом отдельные слова. А теги надо вырезать ещё до разделения.

Comment: Если выделить сначала словосочетания в отдельный массив, то как потом понять какое словосочетания куда вставлять, чтобы не потерять порядок слов?

Comment: Дык эта... сохраняй вместе с выделенной фигнёй и её смещение в исходном тексте. Вот и не потеряешься.

Comment: @Akina, если ты вырежешь теги, то словосочетания добыть уже не получится. Надо всё делать одновременно.

Comment: @Qwertiy *если ты вырежешь теги, то словосочетания добыть уже не получится* Под вырезанием тега разумеется не удаление их из строки (ибо при этом поплывут смещения), а замена на эквивалентное число пробелов. И словосочетания в таком "очищенном" значении выделяются без проблем. Впрочем, я немного не так понял задачу, наверное...

Comment: @Akina, но никто не говорил, что остальные пробелы однократные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть, так? Только пришлось переместить знак вопроса внутрь тега.

```js
let text = "<p>Привет, как <span>твои дела?</span> Это тестовое сообщение.</p>";

let myArray = text.split("<p>").join("").split("</p>");

myArray.pop(myArray.length - 1);

myArray.map((item) => {
  let arr = item
    .split(/(?=<span>)|(?<=<\/span>)/)
    .flatMap(str => str.startsWith('<span>') ?
      str.replace(/^<span>|<\/span>$/g, '') :
      str.trim().split(/\s+/)
    );
  console.log(arr)
});
```

Comment: Да. Со знаком вопроса придумаю что-нибудь, наверное )

Comment: Можно и с вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text = "<p>Привет, как <span>твои дела</span>? Это тестовое сообщение.</p>";

var res = []

text.replace(
  /<\/?p>|<span>([^<]*)<\/span>([^\s<]*)|([^\s<]+)/g,
  (match, span = "", tail = "", word = "") => {
    var cur = span + tail + word
    cur && res.push(cur)
  }
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

С учётом знака вопроса после спана:

```js
var text = "<p>Привет, как <span>твои дела</span>? Это тестовое сообщение.</p>";

var res = text
  .split(/\s+|<\/?p>|<span>([^<]*<\/span>[^\s<]*)/)
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(x => x.replace("</span>", ""))

console.log(res)
```

Если знак вопроса можно поместить отдельно, то проще:

```js
var text = "<p>Привет, как <span>твои дела</span>? Это тестовое сообщение.</p>";

var res = text
  .split(/\s+|<\/?p>|<span>([^<]*)<\/span>/)
  .filter(Boolean)

console.log(res)
```